# NHibernate - Do Not Load Property (Single Query)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, geometry, lazy-loading

A little background about my problem: I'm running NHibernate, and I have a table that contains a geometry in a particular spatial reference, but the system that actively uses it on the web server is using a different spatial reference, so I created an event listener to automatically do projection back and forth on loads, updates, and inserts. This works well overall. Now the problem came up when I created a query against this table, for which the geometry is irrelevant, but the conversion to the custom type and subsequent projection of all results ends up taking quite a bit of time, so I would like to just not load that property.

I figure I have 2 logical options:
1. Lazy load the property
2. Create a separate class that doesn't map that property (but is otherwise identical)

I attempted the lazy loading solution, but as far as I can tell, there's no event listener for me to implement that would catch the lazy load and allow me to do the projection, so all of the geometries end up in Africa. The only solution I see to that problem is to find every time I would want to actually use that property and manually load and project it, but that just seems terrible to me.

**TLDR:** Is there any way in NHibernate to set a property to lazy load (or not load at all) just for a particular query, or would it be better to just create another class and not map the geometry in that one? I don't want the geometry loaded into memory at all, so a projection won't help.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, I would write the query with criteria or QueryOver and exclude the property. You would then project the query results to a DTO or plain old c# object instead of working with the entity directly.

Comment: You know you can load the entities via custom queries right ?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker if I use Criteria or QueryOver, then it will do the mapping to the geometry object before I can project the results into a DTO, would it not?

Comment: @ReverseBlade I would prefer to avoid "magic strings" as much as possible, so I'd like to stay using something along the lines of QueryOver (or even linq) if possible.

edit: in thinking about it, I guess I could construct the query and then grab the results in list form and assign them manually... but something about that still feels off.

Comment: @BenjaminMcGregor: Your mapping would include all properties including the geometry ones. A custom query would not have to access those properties though

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker QueryOver (and by extension, Criteria) use the mapping for the type, so it would end up mapping the geometry. If I wrote a custom HQL or SQL query as ReverseBlade suggested, I could pick the fields I wanted, but I'd like to avoid it if possible. It may just be easier to create a different class that mirrors the one in question except it doesn't have the geometry in it.

Comment: @BenjaminMcGregor: That's not the case, unless I'm misunderstanding. You can exclude the property in a QueryOver query and avoid working with the entity entirely. If you project the query results to a DTO or POCO, you would not be interacting with mapped properties that were excluded from the query at all.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker In the way of QueryOver, there are two types, the generic version, and the aliased version, both of which are tied to a specific type and will use the mapping for that type to hydrate the entity. I also see no way to explicitly tell the query to exclude a specific property either.

Comment: @BenjaminMcGregor: Sure you have to use mapped classes to query with NHibernate. You do not, however, have to hydrate an entity as a query result. You can use `AliasToBeanTransformer` to project the query results to a DTO and avoid loading certain columns completely

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker ooohhhhhh, I was wondering what that did... Ok, so I tested it out. I wanted to keep the interface the same so that changes to the rest of the project would be minimal, but it doesn't appear to be able to map the related objects, so I'm going to try to load it into a flattened DTO I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this for a while, I found a solution that I like. I went back to working with lazy loading the property, but I shifted where I'm doing the projecting to inside of the geometry user type. Now whether it's lazy loaded or not, it will be projected properly, and it makes it more clear that projections are happening in the mapping.

Here's an example of my mapping for the geometry now:

```
Map(m => m.Shape, "SHAPE").CustomType<GeometryType<Wgs84WebMercator, Nad83FloridaGdlAlbers>>().LazyLoad();
```